# Segmentation fault (core dumped) For All commands in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, appium

I am trying to install Appium Automation tool by following the steps from 
[http://testingalert.com/steps-to-setup-appium-on-ubuntu/][1]
But after Step 4: **sudo apt install linuxbrew-wrapper**  we are facing the issue Segmentation fault (core dumped) for all commands in the system.

Am unable to run the **clean, ls** commands also but all commands working **sudo clean, sudo ls** what may the issue and how can i get rid of this issue?.. i read most of the questions posted for Segmentation fault (core dumped) issue but all are saying nam issue but in my case i think it was different.
help me to resolve this issue.
Thanks In advance
Shiva Prasad G

Comment: Wrong site, go to https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: Also, your link to testingalert doesnt work.